# Does there exist a subset of the Euclidean plane $E^2$ with the isometry group of order 5?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, isometry

Would a regular pentagon or a star work?  A few people in my class said no, but I don't see why those wouldn't work

Comment: Because you can have reflectional symmetry, making the isometry group $D_5$ instead.

Comment: @KennyLau Could you please explain this to me?  I have no idea what that means

Comment: $D_n$ is the isometry group of the regular polygon with $n$ sides. Reflection is an isometry.

Comment: @KennyLau so how is that different than what I am looking for?

Comment: Because when you have rotational symmetries and reflectional symmetries, you get a group of order $10$.

Comment: @KennyLau ok thank you! Does this answer make sense? the answer is no there isn't because any shape with 5 reflectional symmetries will also have 5 rotational symmetries, so it will be a group of order 10 and you can't have a shape with less reflectional symmetries that will add up to 5 total symmetries because they will have the same number of reflectional and rotational symmetries, which means the sum is always an even number?

Comment: There can be a shape with 5 rotational symmetries but without any reflectional symmetry.

Comment: @KennyLau could you give an example please?

Comment: The star in the [Hong Kong flag](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/Flag_of_Hong_Kong.svg)

Comment: @KennyLau Thank you! That makes perfect sense